# Is there a suitable replacement for C++, when I would like to write video processing applications?

Tags: programming-languages, haskell, erlang, lisp, video-processing

I want to write a video editing software, and the "logical" conclusion is that the language I must to use is C++... But I don't like it (sorry c++ fans)

I would like to write it with something cool, like Lisp or Haskell or Erlang... But I don't know if the open source implementation of those languages (I don't have money to buy licenses) let me made a competitive software (in the performance area)

What do you think? what do you recommend?

Comment: No offense taken (by me at least). But I still think that for a video editing software your choice will be very limited.

Comment: It all depends on how much time you want to invest in this. If you are willing to write everything from scratch you can probably do it in any language of choice. Just give it a shot with a simple implementation of just a player and see how far you get :)

Comment: Btw, if that's an option to you, you could also glue together high-performance code written in C++ with a high-level language with Foreign-Function-Interface, such as Python, Ruby, Haskell and others

Comment: Removed C++ tag -- this is not a C++ question.

Comment: It's certainly not as cool, but I'd sooner use C than C++ for nearly any project.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can't speak to Lisp, but both Erlang and Haskell are capable of the performance necessary for video processing.  Achieving that performance is likely to be more difficult than with C++ because there are fewer existing libraries in the domain, so you'll have to implement more yourself.  Which means you'll have to be capable of writing high-performance code yourself.  In Haskell I expect this would require a significant investment of time (6 months minimum) to become proficient.

Which language you choose should depend a great deal upon the goals of the project.  If it's a hobby project, or you want to learn a lot about processing algorithms (and therefore don't mind having to do a lot of low-level coding yourself), there's nothing wrong with using an out-of-mainstream language.  Haskell has bindings to a lot of things you would probably want to use eventually, such as a [wrapper for GLSL](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/GPipe).

As somebody working with audio processing (including real-time), I can say that Haskell's performance hasn't been a problem for me.  For a recent project I did write some functions in C, but that was necessary to implement a custom vectorization scheme.  Doing high-level work in Haskell and calling out to C when necessary is a perfectly valid approach, although thankfully it's less necessary now than in the past.

Of course, this presumes a few things about the nature of your project.  If you want something you can use right away, Haskell, Lisp, and Erlang are probably not the languages for you because there are fewer resources.  Have you considered [Processing](http://processing.org/)?  It's Java, I don't know if you consider that better than C++ or worse.

I had motivations besides productivity for working in Haskell (and my productivity took a big hit for a while), without those other goals I wouldn't have persevered.  If you want to write something to use it, stick with what's going to be most productive.  If you have other motivations, tell us what they are and it's more likely people will make helpful suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth, [Wings3D](http://wings3d.com/) is written in Erlang.

You could always try [D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_(programming_language)), if you want something somewhat similar to C++ but not C++.  Also, D could use some love.

Comment: Does it do any video processing? See the question.

Answer (score 3):

For both Haskell and Erlang, the open source implementation *is* the standard, most efficient available implementation available. There's no reason that Haskell shouldn't be performant enough for your needs -- for video stuff I assume you'll be using matrices and such. There are quality bindings available for BLAS & co for Haskell. I don't know of a great deal of existing video editing work, but Alberto Ruiz (the author of HMatrix) has done work with Haskell and computer vision: http://dis.um.es/profesores/alberto/research.html

There's also a great deal of work on sound libraries and processing in Haskell.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the language that gives me the best coverage by third-party libraries for what I'm trying to do; for manipulating video data that's probably going to be a mainstream language like C++.

If this project is for fun/to learn a new language then by all means, take the road less traveled. But if this is something you need to ship in a reasonable amount of time, avoiding the best tools for the job because you don't like them is unsound strategy.

Comment: It's only a exercise, some kind of hobby project. The deadline is the day of my death :)

Answer (score 1):

That depends at least on what's your goal with the project. If it's a hobby project and you want to learn a different language, then you should choose that language. In this case, however, I assume you're familiar with video processing. On the other hand, if you want to learn about video processing, I'd recommend using a language you are already comfortable with.

Now, if it's a professional project of a decent size (video processing software can be huge) you should probably consider using different languages for different things. The kind of systems I work with usually require writing some code in C (for efficiency reasons), but we always try to keep that to de indispensable minimum and use a higher level language for most of the system behaviour (we use erlang, but that applies to any other higher level language).

IMO, writing big systems in C or C++ is almost a suicide. There are projects that succeed, but I find that much harder than complementing the C part with higher level languages.

Answer (score 1):

There is already some video streaming server written in Erlang http://erlyvideo.org/. You can look for some inspiration https://github.com/erlyvideo/erlyvideo.